# join spark df with list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to use join/filter out spark RDD/DF with List

I have list and spark RDD

```
val list = List(12345,222222,333333,444444,555555,666666)

val friendPF=Seq(("bob", "2015-01-13", 12345), ("alicsdsdse", "2015-04-23",112120),("alice", "2015-04-23",1021212),("alsddsdsice", "2015-04-23",112120),("four", "2015-04-23",44444),("three", "2015-04-23",333333),("two", "2015-04-23",222222),("five", "2015-04-23",555555),("otowowo", "2015-04-23",1121210),("six", "2015-04-23",666666)).toDF("name","date","id")
```

friendPF.show

```
+-----------+----------+-------+
|       name|      date|     id|
+-----------+----------+-------+
|        bob|2015-01-13|  12345|
| alicsdsdse|2015-04-23| 112120|
|      alice|2015-04-23|1021212|
|alsddsdsice|2015-04-23| 112120|
|       four|2015-04-23|  44444|
|      three|2015-04-23| 333333|
|        two|2015-04-23| 222222|
|       five|2015-04-23| 555555|
|    otowowo|2015-04-23|1121210|
|        six|2015-04-23| 666666|
+-----------+----------+-------+
```

how to use join to get the matching id's from the given rdd?

Comment: you can convert the list to string and use lit and contains to filter . thats the easierst solution otherwise you would have to use a udf function

Answer (score 1):

Convert your `list` RDD into dataframe as follows

```
val listDF = List(12345,222222,333333,444444,555555,666666).toDF("id")
```

Now join two dataframes

```
friendPF.as("rel").
    join(listDF.as("ids"),  $"ids.id" === $"rel.id").
    select( $"rel.name", $"rel.date",$"rel.id").show()
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to join, use `isin`:

```
friendsPF
.where($"id".isin(list:_*))
.show()
```